# Проблема параллельного выполнения транзакций в mysql

Tags: mysql, transaction, deadlock

Есть неоплаченный счет. После оплаты, по колбеку платежной системы создается платеж на сумму N. + выставляется статус счета в "Оплачен". Транзакция стартует только в случае, если счет в состоянии "ожидает оплаты".

Проблема: Платежная система присылает 2 запроса по колбеку с разницей 1 секунда.
И иногда возникает ситуация, что запускается 2ая транзакция оплаты счета параллельно.
Это приводит к 2ум результатам:
1. 70% - возникает deadlock. 
2. 30% - обе транзакции завершаются успехом и в базу записывается платеж 2 раза.

Как с этим правильно бороться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Транзакция стартует только в случае, если счет в состоянии "ожидает оплаты".

Проверяйте статус внутри транзакции, при том захватывая необходимую блокировку. Тогда конкурентные запросы встанут в очередь на получении блокировки.

```
begin;
select .. from tablename where uid = ? and status = 'wait_payment' for update;
```

Если 0 строк в результате - то делаете commit (или rollback) и отлуп "такого платежа нет".

Если 1 строка нашлась - то обновляете статус на тот, который нужен и в этой же транзакции делаете другие необходимые действия.

Все конкурентные запросы встанут в очереди на получении блокировки `for update`, эту блокировку единовременно может удерживать только одна транзакция. Если держащая блокировку транзакция отменится, то блокировку захватит следующий ожидающий поток и будет выполняться только он один. Если транзакция зафиксируется и изменит статус строки - то `select .. for update` прочитает обновлённую версию строки и, соответственно, вернёт 0 строк - что будет опять же штатной реакцией, без повторной обработки действия.

---

В зависимости от реализации платёжной системы может потребоваться вынести проверку статуса оплаты с СУБД на приложение - чтобы корректно сформировать на повторные запросы от платёжной системы ответы "транзакция обработана" вместо "транзакция не найдена". Т.е. если в базе заказ уже записан как оплаченный, то ответить платёжке "ок", но больше ничего не делать.